# How can i center site header in nav with random width of suff around?

Tags: html, css, web, web-deployment

What i want is almost same as this programs header,

[image: Desired program header]

The Title is completely centered despite of the random width of the aside stuff.
Yeah If course i am not making a software but still i want almost this kind of random stuff around AND
Still The TITLE MUST BE NEATLY CENTERED

> Please, Don't give me advice like 'Just use grid/flex' 
> Instead, Tell me how am i gonna use the grid/flex to center it ?? (I am trying and ,,, still Cant solve it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox won't really work because the title must be centered within the *entire* header—not in the remaining space between the left and right items. Still, you can use flexbox to pin the left/right items to their respective corners. For the title, use absolute positioning within a relative container (the header).

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: transalteX(-50%); 
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">
    <span>item</span>
    <span>longer item here</span>    
  </div>
  <div class="title">title</div>
  <div class="right">
    <span>item</span>
    <span>item</span>    
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Huh, looks like i got to work with \@media but still neat enough

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using `position: absolute;` with `left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)  translateY(-50%);`

but in this case you have to test your app with any width possible to make sure the text wont get one above another

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: #212121;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f1f2f3;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

p.left {
  float: left;
}

p.right {
  float: right;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)  translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <p class="left">stuff</p>
    <p class="center">center</p>
    <p class="right">stuff</p>
    <p class="right">stuff</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Mistake heppens after many downotes in other questions also, So i am just to irritated, Sorry Man..

Comment: Coool (ignore: theres a limit in comment Wow)