# css align equally some item of p tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is HTML

```css
.item p {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
.item p {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        max-width: 15ch;
        vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="item">
        <img src="image.png">
        <p>short namne</p>
        <p>price</p>
</div>

 <div class="item">
        <img src="image.png">
        <p>long name long name long name</p>
</div>
```

I want the last one will be very right always and the 2nd will be in the middle and the first one will always be left.

currently this is only in line positioned in inline, no align ment. i want alight left, center, right

like i want:

```
img                                   short name                                      price
```

but current it showing like this but i dont want like ths:

```
img short name price
```

can anyone help to get it done?

Comment: Are you looking for `flex`? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: i dont if flex works but i tried i couldnt do it

Comment: I think flex is the cleanest solution for this. Follow the guide, it's rather simple. If you get stuck, post your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i center site header in nav with random width of suff around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62547625/how-can-i-center-site-header-in-nav-with-random-width-of-suff-around)

Comment: No, this is not my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add [`justify-content: space-between`](https://cssreference.io/property/justify-content/) to `.item`

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item p {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.item p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 15ch;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="image.png">
  <p>short namne</p>
  <p>price</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="image.png">
  <p>long name long name long name</p>
  <p></p> <!-- added -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as CSS for **item** class

```
.item {
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Furthermore, you could have a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more info on CSS flexbox.